# firebase jobdispatcher doesn't schedule my job

Tags: android, android-service, android-jobscheduler, firebase-job-dispatcher

in hydration app i have a class to schedule the job`and I planed to run my service after one minute but it doesn't work and there is an error in WaterReminderFirebaseJobService class that say that onstartjob() method must be called on main thread and i tried to create a class that extends from asynctask the error disappear but the job still not working 
how can i solve my problem?

jobservice class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.Job;
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobParameters;
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobService;
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.RetryStrategy;

public class WaterReminderFirebaseJobService extends JobService {

    private AsyncTask mBackgroundTask;
    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(final JobParameters jobParameters) {
        mBackgroundTask = new AsyncTask() {
            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
                jobFinished(jobParameters, false);
            }

        };

        mBackgroundTask.execute();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {

        if (mBackgroundTask != null) mBackgroundTask.cancel(true);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and ReminderUtilties

```
public class ReminderUtilties {
    private static final int REMINDER_INTERVAL_MINUTES = 1;
    private static final int REMINDER_INTERVAL_SECONDS = (int) (TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(REMINDER_INTERVAL_MINUTES));
    private static final int SYNC_FLEXTIME_SECONDS = REMINDER_INTERVAL_SECONDS;
    private static final String REMINDER_JOB_TAG = "hydration_reminder_tag";
    private static boolean sInitialized;
    synchronized public static void scheduleChargingReminder(@NonNull final Context context) {
        if (sInitialized) return;
        Driver driver = new GooglePlayDriver(context);
        FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(driver);
        Job constraintReminderJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                .setService(WaterReminderFirebaseJobService.class).setTag(REMINDER_JOB_TAG)
                .setConstraints(Constraint.DEVICE_CHARGING).setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER).setRecurring(true)
                .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(
                        REMINDER_INTERVAL_SECONDS,
                        REMINDER_INTERVAL_SECONDS + SYNC_FLEXTIME_SECONDS)).setReplaceCurrent(true).build();
        dispatcher.schedule(constraintReminderJob);
        sInitialized = true;
    }

}
```

this is main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    private TextView mWaterCountDisplay;
    private TextView mChargingCountDisplay;
    private ImageView mChargingImageView;

    private Toast mToast;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWaterCountDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_water_count);
        mChargingCountDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_charging_reminder_count);
        mChargingImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_power_increment);

        updateWaterCount();
        updateChargingReminderCount();
        ReminderUtilties.scheduleChargingReminder(this);

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    }

    private void updateWaterCount() {
        int waterCount = PreferenceUtilities.getWaterCount(this);
        mWaterCountDisplay.setText(waterCount+"");
    }

    private void updateChargingReminderCount() {
        int chargingReminders = PreferenceUtilities.getChargingReminderCount(this);
        String formattedChargingReminders = getResources().getQuantityString(
                R.plurals.charge_notification_count, chargingReminders, chargingReminders);
        mChargingCountDisplay.setText(formattedChargingReminders);

    }

    public void incrementWater(View view) {
        if (mToast != null) mToast.cancel();
        mToast = Toast.makeText(this, R.string.water_chug_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        mToast.show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WaterReminderIntentService.class);
        intent.setAction(ReminderTasks.ACTION_INCREMENT_WATER_COUNT);
        startService(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        /** Cleanup the shared preference listener **/
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        prefs.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        if (PreferenceUtilities.KEY_WATER_COUNT.equals(key)) {
            updateWaterCount();
        } else if (PreferenceUtilities.KEY_CHARGING_REMINDER_COUNT.equals(key)) {
            updateChargingReminderCount();
        }
    }
    public  void textNotification(View view){
        NotificationUtilties.remindUserBecauseCharging(this);
    }
}
```

and ReminderTask class is

```
public class ReminderTasks {
    public static final String ACTION_INCREMENT_WATER_COUNT="increment_water_count";
    public static final String ACTION_DISMISS_NOTIFICATION = "dismiss_notification";
    public static final String ACTION_CHARGING_REMINDER = "charging_reminder";
    public static void executeTask(Context context,String action){
        if(ACTION_INCREMENT_WATER_COUNT.equals(action)){
            incrementWaterCount(context);
            NotificationUtilties.clearAllNotification(context);
        }else if (ACTION_DISMISS_NOTIFICATION.equals(action)){
            NotificationUtilties.clearAllNotification(context);
        }else if(ACTION_CHARGING_REMINDER.equals(action)){
            PreferenceUtilities.incrementChargingReminderCount(context);
            NotificationUtilties.remindUserBecauseCharging(context);
        }
    }
    private static void incrementWaterCount(Context context){
        PreferenceUtilities.incrementWaterCount(context);
    }
}
```

and preferenceUtilties

```
public final class PreferenceUtilities {

    public static final String KEY_WATER_COUNT = "water-count";
    public static final String KEY_CHARGING_REMINDER_COUNT = "charging-reminder-count";

    private static final int DEFAULT_COUNT = 0;

    synchronized private static void setWaterCount(Context context, int glassesOfWater) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt(KEY_WATER_COUNT, glassesOfWater);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static int getWaterCount(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        int glassesOfWater = prefs.getInt(KEY_WATER_COUNT, DEFAULT_COUNT);
        return glassesOfWater;
    }

    synchronized public static void incrementWaterCount(Context context) {
        int waterCount = PreferenceUtilities.getWaterCount(context);
        PreferenceUtilities.setWaterCount(context, ++waterCount);
    }

    synchronized public static void incrementChargingReminderCount(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        int chargingReminders = prefs.getInt(KEY_CHARGING_REMINDER_COUNT, DEFAULT_COUNT);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt(KEY_CHARGING_REMINDER_COUNT, ++chargingReminders);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static int getChargingReminderCount(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        int chargingReminders = prefs.getInt(KEY_CHARGING_REMINDER_COUNT, DEFAULT_COUNT);
        return chargingReminders;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using jetpack workmanager because
"WorkManager has a lot of nice features but its main goal is to use the JobScheduler's API on older devices"... Wait, but we already have some backports. What's wrong with them? To cut it short:

FireaseJobDispatcher is fine but it requires Google Play to schedule jobs which isn't good if we're targeting China, for example.

Evernote's AndroidJob is an excellent backport with a lot of functionality. Imho, it was the best choice for scheduling any work. But now the latest version of the library uses the aforementioned WorkManager under the hood. And, unfortunately, sooner or later the library will be deprecated

https://androidwave.com/scheduling-recurring-task-in-android-workmanager/